# Replacement of com.android.build.api.transform.Transform classes

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-gradle-plugin-7

I could see in the android [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/7.0/com/android/build/api/transform/Transform) that `Transform` classes are deprecated but I could not see the new API which we should use instead of Transform classes.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found this news about it: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#transform-removed

It seems like its replacement isn't a single new class, but rather a combination of tools available in the new "androidComponents", according to what they said there... Though I'm still not sure what exactly within androidComponents can achieve the same results.

EDIT:

The same link I posted above has alternatives to the Transform API right below the removal notice. They have alternatives depending on the use case, one for when you need to [instrument classes using plain ASM](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#support_for_transforming_bytecode), another for when you want to [add new classes on top of the project's ones](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#support_for_adding_generated_classes_to_your_app), and another one to [transform the whole project classes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin-api-updates#support_for_transformations_based_on_whole_program_analysis), similarly to the deprecated Transform API, though they recommend using it with caution due to its possible performance penalties to the compilation process.

Comment: Well...it seems that they are going to make the work harder and not easier with any update...If you need more information about the issue, add to **gradle.properties** file the `android.debug.obsoleteApi=true` parameter.